# Const pointer and pointer to const

Tags: c++, pointers

Instead of doing this:

```
int* const p;
```

And this:

```
const int* p;
```

Couldn't you make it easier to read by doing:

```
typedef int* ptr;
const ptr p; //Constant pointer to an integer
```

And:

```
typedef const int ptr;
ptr* p; //Pointer to a constant integer
```

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: Answer: you totally can, but don't overdo it or you'll make your code hard to understand (if readers have to continuously refer to typedefs).

Comment: It's actually harder because now I have to go look up what a `ptr` is in your code.

Comment: @xlc "Couldn't you make it easier to read by doing…?"

Comment: I do not like using const in a typedef except for in special cases.  Like mneonneo said, it can make code hard to understand and the use of the type is not as flexible.

Comment: wouldnt it be easy if you have intellisense and a parser?

Comment: This works, but it is not idiomatic. Every C and C++ programmer with more than a week of experience already knows how to read `const int *` and `int *const`. All you are doing here is making it a little harder for experienced people to read your code, for the possible (and arguably questionable) benefit for novices.

Comment: And on the point about putting your mouse over it to show you the type: would you really want to have to type something out, take your hands off the keyboard, hover your mouse on it, realize its not what you want, and then repeat several times until you get the correct type?

Comment: @LukasSchmit I guess but its a pretty quick process to do so.

Comment: As @Nemo has pointed out, there is a big difference between ***can*** and ***should***.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's really no reason to do that. Not only would it make your code less readable, but it doesn't really make sense.

```
typedef const int ptr;
```

^ that makes no sense - it is a const int but you call it a pointer.
Just save yourself and the readers and type out

```
const int* ptr;
```

EDIT:

to directly answer your question: **no, you would NOT make it easier.**

EDIT #2

another point, what happens when you have

```
typedef const int ptr;
typedef const long ptr;
typedef const float ptr;
```

not only does it not make sense, since they aren't pointers, but now you have a bunch of things called ptr, and you will get confused about what you are actually writing.

Comment: In visual studio its easy to see what somethig is - put your cursor over it and it gives youthe description.

Comment: @SusanYanders well, that's one ide. if you find it really helps you, then you can do it. But trust me, if you have a project over 100 lines of code, it is going to make you shoot yourself if you typedef everything.

Comment: @SusanYanders Alright, glad that I could be of assistance. I'm stil pretty new to c++ as well :)

Comment: See also Chapter 5 "Typedefs" of the [Linux Coding Standards](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/CodingStyle) for the five cases where they allow typedefs. "In general, a pointer, or a struct that has elements that can reasonably be directly accessed should _never_ be a typedef."

Comment: +1 for the second edit about intelligently naming typedefs.  I cringed when I saw the typedef named "ptr" and not even "int_ptr" or something similar--reminds me of the horrors of macros.

Comment: @Prime I wasnt aiming at giving the typedef a good nme. That wasnt my question.

Answer (score 0):

Go through the below link. Author has clearly explained when to make use of typedef and when to not. If I start explaining, this blog will grow bigger.

http://www.oualline.com/books.free/style/c06.pdf

Comment: Any chance ther is an html version?

Comment: http://www.oualline.com/books.free/style/c06.html

Answer (score 0):

`typedef` ought to be used when you have a specific need for a new type to *represent something*.  Just making a `typedef` to save typing is senseless and will result in harder-to-read code.

An example of a good typedef to hide a `const` or `volatile` qualifier would be e.g. for a read-only hardware register (common in embedded software development). You'd write something like

```
typedef const volatile int *ro_reg_t; /* readonly hardware register */
```

and then declare your hardware registers thus:

```
const ro_reg_t CHIP_VERSION = (void *)0x4240000c;
```

so that you can now write

```
int val = *CHIP_VERSION;
```

but not

```
CHIP_VERSION = 0xf00d;
```

or

```
*CHIP_VERSION = 0xbaad;
```